# C# foreach unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, covariance

Why C# compiler allows this to compile and throws runtime exception when run?

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      IEnumerable<Test> list = new List<Test>() { new Test() };

      foreach(IDisposable item in list)
      {

      }
   }
}

public class Test
{

}
```

This does compile with any interface and it doesn't compile if you replace IDisposable with concrete class.

Comment: It compiles because there may exist instances that derive from `Test` which **do** implement `IDisposable`. Effectivly the foreach tries to cast every element to the interface and throws an exception if this fails. The same as if you´d write `(IDisposable)currentElement`. However I can´t see why it shouldn´t compile on the concrete class.

Comment: According to my fiddle that compiles just fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Up9nU

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Yes, that's the point of the question.

Comment: you could make sure you won't run into an exception by using `foreach (IDisposable item in list.OfType<IDisposable>())` but I guess that's not the point

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `foreach` loop has an implicit cast in it. It's roughly like this:

```
using (IEnumerator<Test> iterator = list.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        IDisposable item = (IDisposable) iterator.Current;
        // Body of foreach loop here
    }
}
```

Back before generics, that was much handier than having to cast in the source code. Now it's not so important, but it would be odd for it to not compile. Note that the compiler *will* check that it's at least *feasible*. If you use `foreach (string item in list)` that wouldn't compile, because a `Test` can't be a `string` - but a `Test` *can* be an `IDisposable`, because it could refer to an instance of a subclass of `Test` that implements `IDisposable`. If you make the `Test` class sealed, it will fail to compile even with `IDisposable`, too, because then a `Test` instance can't implement `IDisposable`.

Basically, it will compile if a cast from `Test` to the iteration type would compile, and will fail to compile otherwise. But it'll fail at execution time if a normal cast would fail at execution time, too.